# CSP Recursive Calls Fail with with Range(a,b) but not Explicit Range

Tags: python

[Sudoku](https://leetcode.com/problems/sudoku-solver/) is a well known CSP and, in this case, LC problem. I don't need the solution, which follows.

My question is why does `self.DOMAIN = "123456789"` (line #4) work, whereas `self.DOMAIN = map(str, range(1, 10))` (line #5) does not? Are they not equivalent?

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.SIZE = 9
        # self.DOMAIN = map(str, range(1, self.SIZE + 1)) # THIS DES NOT WORK NOT WORK
        self.DOMAIN = "123456789" # THIS WORKS
        self.EMPTY = "."

        from collections import defaultdict
        self.rows = defaultdict(set) # {row:set}
        self.cols = defaultdict(set) # {col:set}
        self.boxs = defaultdict(set) # {box:set}
        
        self.row_idx = lambda cell: cell // self.SIZE # determines row from cell num
        self.col_idx = lambda cell: cell % self.SIZE  # determins col from cell num
        self.box_idx = lambda r, c: (r // 3) * 3 + c // 3 # determines box from row, col
        
        
    def solveSudoku(self, board: List[List[str]]) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify board in-place instead.
        """
        assert(len(board) == self.SIZE and len(board[0]) == self.SIZE), \
        "Sudoku board must be 9x9 in dimensions"
        
        # Initialize board state
        self.board = board
        for r in range(self.SIZE):
            for c in range(self.SIZE):
                val = self.board[r][c]
                if val != self.EMPTY:
                    self.rows[r].add(val)
                    self.cols[c].add(val)
                    self.boxs[self.box_idx(r, c)].add(val)
        
        # Begin backtracking search from the first cell
        self.backtrack(0)
        
    def backtrack(self, cell):
        if cell == 81:
            # all values have been set and we are outside the board range
            return True
        
        r, c = self.row_idx(cell), self.col_idx(cell)
        if self.board[r][c] != self.EMPTY:
            # nothing to do, continue search
            return self.backtrack(cell + 1)
        
        # explore values in the domain for this cell
        for candidate_val in self.DOMAIN:
            if self.is_valid(r, c, candidate_val):
                # place candidate
                self.board[r][c] = candidate_val
                self.rows[r].add(candidate_val)
                self.cols[c].add(candidate_val)
                self.boxs[self.box_idx(r, c)].add(candidate_val)
                
                # continue search
                if self.backtrack(cell + 1):
                    return True
                
                # remove candidate and backtrack
                self.board[r][c] = self.EMPTY
                self.rows[r].remove(candidate_val)
                self.cols[c].remove(candidate_val)
                self.boxs[self.box_idx(r, c)].remove(candidate_val)
        
        # no solution found for all values in the domain for this cell 
        return False
        
    def is_valid(self, r, c, val):
        """ Returns whether a value can be placed in board[r][c] in the current game state """
        
        if val in self.rows[r]:
            return False
        if val in self.cols[c]:
            return False
        if val in self.boxs[self.box_idx(r, c)]:
            return False
        return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are suffering confusion between "generator" and "container".
Consult `type( ... )` to tell the difference between them.

Python generators are "lazy", for excellent technical reasons.
Sometimes we can get away with just evaluating
the first K items of an infinite generator.

In your method you want everything greedily pulled out,
and then stored in a container.
The conventional way to phrase this is to wrap `map` with `list`:

```
self.DOMAIN = list(map(str, range(1, 10)))
```

or perhaps in your case you would prefer that `.join` pull them out:

```
self.DOMAIN = ''.join(map(str, range(1, 10)))
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into the distinction.
"Python generators are "lazy", for excellent technical reasons." May you elaborate or provide some resources as to why?

Comment: x kj 283': Well, the obvious way is they don't contain all the data at once, they generate it as needed.

Comment: xkj283, I thought I explained that when I observed, "Sometimes we can get away with just evaluating the first K items of an infinite generator," e.g. `head(gen)` might set K=1 and extract just the 1st item then discard the generator. When we choose NOT to evaluate the next() item, we conserve both memory and CPU cycles. Those are good reasons for designing around a generator rather than a container, especially if a library routine isn't sure how many of the results each caller will actually care about.